# Put a slider bar in a canvas for control the volume

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs

I am trying to add a slide bar (like this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/sliders/) in a canvas to control the volume of the sound using SoundJS .

I tried to search on google some information about a slidebar in a canvas but there is nothing

Here i just need some informations and a way to go for control the sound of my game and not only mute or unmute it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put any DOM elements inside a canvas. Canvas is just a bitmap and any tags inside the canvas tag will be ignored by browsers which support canvas.

You can however wrap the canvas and an input control inside for example a div element this way:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <canvas width=800 height=600 id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
    <input id="volume" type=range min=0 max=100 value=50 >
</div>
```

Then use CSS to place the slider on top of the canvas.

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    }
.wrapper > canvas,
.wrapper > input {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    }
.wrapper > input {
    right:10px;    /* places the slider */
    top:10px;
    }
```

Then set the audio element's volume:

```
audio.volume = volume.value * 0.01;
```

The other way is to implement all the logic yourselves for a slider if you need it to be a part of canvas itself for styling or other reasons. A DOM element on top of canvas can slow down the performance of canvas so this can be an essential factor in some cases where performance is critical.

For this you need to declare a virtual region for the slider on your canvas and register mouse events up, down and move on the canvas element.

Draw a knob by converting its current value into a position within its region, that when mouse is clicked in this region you move the knob around inside that region and convert its position to a normalized value which you then use for volume.

This is a whole little project on its own, but the simplest way is to place an input element on top of the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a input range?

```
<input style="float: left; padding: 3px; margin-right: 3px;" id="fontSlider" type="range" name="points" value="15" min="1" max="100" step="1"/>
<input type="text" value="" id="value"/>
```

Then get the value from the textbox or just the value from the range...

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var Values = $( "#fontSlider" ).val();
  $("#value").val(Values);   
        $("#fontSlider").change(        
            function () {
            var Values = $( "#fontSlider" ).val();
                $("#value").val(Values);
            }            
        );
    });
```

DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/bowenac/zMn5N/1/

Comment: I think i cant put an input in a canvas no ?

Comment: Yes I believe you can. Try it out and let me know haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KineticJS for that. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-shapes-horizontally-or-vertically-tutorial/

However, is there any reason why you can't use a slider bar, as in  `<input type="range" name="Volume" min="1" max="11">` to do that?

Comment: I think i cant put an input on a canvas no ?

Comment: You mention a game, is it a mobile app? I guess that if you really wanted to use it on a canvas you could add an onClick attribute and then use `getMousepos()` to determine where on the slider bar the user clicked and (if you want to use a slider), use `requestAnimFrame` to move it.

Comment: Its a game in <canvas> !
and to draw this slider do you have some idea ?

Comment: See http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/ I'll try to make some example code if you want. Might I add though that depending on the game KineticJS might prove much more useful anyways.

Answer (score 0):

We use jquery sliders in the SoundJS [Test Suite demo](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/blob/master/examples/TestSuite.html) which you can check out in the github repo.  Hope that helps.